# Can't modify position of a plot element because it's taken from a factor

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am building a plot where I put points and errorbars, with one coordinate being continuous numeric value and another one comes from the factor:

```
test <- read.table(header=T, text='
group gene val
  A   gene1 1
  B   gene1 1.1
  A   gene2 2.5
  B   gene2 2.4
  A   gene3 0.5
  B   gene3 0.6')

ggplot(data=test,aes(x=val,y=gene,color=group))+
  geom_point(aes(color=group))+
  geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin=val-0.2,xmax=val+0.2),height=0.1,size=1)
```

[image: sample plot]

As you can see, the lines overlap, so I would like to shift them up/down just a little bit (something like a `jitter` but it can be a fixed distance). But if I try to modify `y` in `geom_errorbarh` with something like `y=gene+0.01`, I get an error: `In Ops.factor(gene, 0.01) : ‘+’ not meaningful for factors`.

(P.S. feel free to correct the title to make it more informative - my English is not very good, sorry)

Comment: Use ?position_dodge

Comment: @Roland, if I try to add `position='dodge'` in my `geom_errorbarh()`, it gives a warning `position_dodge requires non-overlapping x intervals`.

Comment: so far my workaround is to flip coordinates, use `geom_errorbar()` with `position='dodge'` and then `coord_flip()`

Comment: OK, apparently you've managed to solve your problem.

Comment: The factors based on integers, so you could use `y = as.numeric(gene) + .1)`.  Sounds like you came up with a solution in the meantime, so you could put it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Package `ggstance` (see [the github repository](https://github.com/lionel-/ggstance)) is a ggplot2 extension for horizontal geoms.  It allows vertical dodging.

Install from github via `devtools::install_github("lionel-/ggstance")`

```
library(ggstance)

pos = position_dodgev(height = .5)

ggplot(data = test, aes(x = val, y = gene, color = group))+
    geom_point(position = pos)+
    geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin = val-0.2, xmax = val+0.2), 
                width = .25, size = 1, position = pos)
```